# Can't click on ionicon within touchableopacity react native

Tags: react-native

I use an IonIcon for a button in react native by wrapping it on a touchable opacity but when I tried to click on the icon it wont do the onpress function if I click on the outside of the icon within the touchable opacity it will trigger the onpress function (ex. click on the text)

here is my code

```js
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Colors, Text } from "react-native-paper";
import Ionicons from "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { navigate } from "../../utils/RootNavigation";

const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height

export default function HomeNavigation() {
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TouchableOpacity 
    style={styles.button}
    activeOpacity={1}
    onPress={() => {
      navigate("MenuNavigator",{
        screen:"History",
       })
    }}>
      <Ionicons 
         name="calendar-outline" 
         color={Colors.blue800} 
         size={32}
      />
      <Text style={styles.label}>History</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity
       style={styles.button}
       activeOpacity={1}
       onPress={() => {
         navigate("MenuNavigator",{
           screen:"File",
         })
       }}>
         <Ionicons 
            name="briefcase-outline" 
            color={Colors.blue800} 
            size={32}
          />
          <Text style={styles.label}>Files</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
)}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        paddingVertical: 16,
        paddingHorizontal: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 24,
        height: 'auto',
        flex: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        borderRadius: 8,
        shadowColor: Colors.black,
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: -4,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.07,
        shadowRadius: 8,
        elevation: 2,
        marginTop: -windowHeight*0.05      
    },
    button: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 'auto',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    label: {
        marginTop: 8,
        fontSize: 12,
        textAlign: 'center',
    }
})
```

Home Navigation is a component that showed on my main page

main page code

```js
*Other import
import HomeNavigation from "../components/HomeNavigation";

export default function Homepage({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
       <ScrollView 
          style={styles.container}
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 32 }}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
          }
        >
         <View>*User info*</View>
         <HomeNavigation />
       </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: please add full code so that we can check if it's an import issue or issue with the parent component or what

Comment: i've updated my code, pls check it

Comment: that's not a full code add code of whole file with imports

Comment: updated for the full code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the child with `<View></View>` or `<></>`. TouchableOpacity cannot propagate the touch event to all children.

```
         <TouchableOpacity 
            style={styles.button}
            activeOpacity={1}
            onPress={() => {
                navigate("MenuNavigator",{
                    screen:"History",
                })
            }}>
            <>
                <Ionicons 
                    name="calendar-outline" 
                    color={Colors.blue800} 
                    size={32}
                    />
                <Text style={styles.label}>History</Text>
            </>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: still cant click on the icon

Comment: Could you give me more detail about your code? Because it looks fine. And possible there are issues in parent components.

Comment: Would you mind to share your styles.button?

Comment: i've update my code above, pls check it